# Why effective number of parameters in K nearest neighbor is N/k?

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour, degrees-of-freedom

Bellow is my deduction:

According to the definition of k-NN fit, we have
$$\hat{Y}(x) = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{x_i \in N_k(x)}^{N}= \frac{1}{k}diag(a_1, a_2,..., a_N)y$$
where $N_k(x)$ is the neighborhood of $x$ defined by the k closest points $x_i$ in the training sample, and $diag(a_1, a_2,..., a_N)$ is a diagonal matrix, if $x_i \in N_k(x)$, $a_i=1$, else $a_i=0$.

Hence, the effective degrees-of-freedom
$$df({S}) = trace({S})=trace(\frac{1}{k}diag(a_1, a_2,..., a_N))=\frac{trace(diag(a_1, a_2,..., a_N))}{K}=1$$

---

What's wrong with my deduction?

Comment: If $Y$ is multivariate normal, $\hat{Y}(x)$ is a linear combination of $k$-normal random variates. If the variance is unknown, the degrees of freedom depend on how you estimate the variance. Are you using $\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \hat{Y}(x))^2 = SSYY$?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I misunderstood the definition of $S$. Maybe below is a right deduction.

According to the definition of k-NN fit, we have
$$\hat{Y}(x) = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{x_i \in N_k(x)}^{N}= \frac{1}{k}\boldsymbol{I}_N\boldsymbol{y}$$

where $N_k(x)$ is the neighborhood of $x$ defined 
by the k closest points $x_i$ in the training sample, $\boldsymbol{I_N}$ is a $1*N$ row vector and the i-th element $\boldsymbol{I_N}(i)=1$ if $x_i \in N_k(x)$, else $\boldsymbol{I_N}(i)=0$

Suppose we stack the outcomes $y_1, y_2, ..., y_N$ into a vector $\boldsymbol{y}$ , and
similarly for the predictions $\boldsymbol{\hat{y}}$. Then the fitting method is one for 
which we can write
        $$\boldsymbol{\hat{y}}= \boldsymbol{Sy}$$
        where $\boldsymbol{S}$ is an $N*N$ matrix depending on the input vectors $x_i$ but not on the $y_i$.

Hence, the effective degrees-of-freedom is
$$df(\boldsymbol{S}) = trace(\boldsymbol{S})=trace(\frac{1}{k}\boldsymbol{I}_{N*N}) \approx \frac{N}{K}$$